# OrderBy GroupBy using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

I have an issue with my linq query.
There are two tables, `Thread` and `Post`.
It is built like a forum.

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostID { get; set; }
    public int ThreadID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    public virtual Thread Thread { get; set; }
}

public class Thread
{
    public int ThreadID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

Threads:
"1, Thread A"
"2, Thread B"

Posts:
"1, 1, 01.01.15"
"2, 1, 02.01.15"
"3, 1, 03.01.15"
"4, 2, 01.01.15"

Expected result:
"3, 1, 03.01.15"
"4, 2, 01.01.15"
```

I would like to get all posts grouped by `ThreadID`, but I want it to be sorted by the latest post using `Time`.

This is my query.

```
Posts.OrderByDescending(x => x.Time).GroupBy(x => x.ThreadID).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());
```

This return distinct posts, but it finds the oldest post, not the newest.

If I use this code.

```
Posts.OrderByDescending(x => x.Time)
```

I get the sorting corerct, but not the distinct posts.

What am I missing?

Comment: First of all, people who down vote, please comment on why you down vote. Second, this does not solve the issue. Now I get the list grouped correctly, and it also looks lite it is sorted correctly, but the post that is returned for each group is the oldest, not the newest.

Comment: Post your defintions of *Thread* and *Post* classes , create a list ( *Posts* ) and fill with sample data, show your code about how you use it (this is OK) and ask the expected output. This is how a good question can be. I good question can be answered by copying  and pasting it into our VS and working on it.

Comment: Ok, question updated. Please remove down votes if the question is fulfilling your requirements.

Comment: @Martin  OK it is an improvement but writing `Threads: "1, Thread A"` does solve anything. How can I write a code to test it. Should I do it by myself just because you are lazy to prepare a good question. Post a sample list (written in c# filling the *Posts* list)

Comment: @I4V: First time I came a cross this level of detail. No one threatens you into answering my question, and I find  your critique quite unreasonable. I see that there are other constructive answers comming in, and I will focus on them. Have a nice day.

Comment: @Martin good day, I am hoping at least, you have learnt what to do when asking a good question.

Comment: @I4V: Sorry, wrong button. Not interested in yours either.

Comment: @Martin http://sscce.org/

Comment: @I4V: Nice, you're even running an organization now. I will keep it in mind for later. But I still think it is a bit harsh to keep the down vote even after i edited my post. It was not that badly presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the latest post in each thread, try this:

```
Posts.GroupBy(x => x.ThreadID)
     .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Time).FirstOrDefault())
     .OrderByDescending(x => x.Time);
```

If you want *all* posts, grouped by thread, in the order of the latest post within the thread, then try this:

```
Posts.OrderByDescending(x => x.Time)
     .GroupBy(x => x.ThreadID)
     .SelectMany(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Time));
```

Two order-by statements are probably needed, as the first will sort the entire list by time, and the second will ensure the items are still sorted after grouping.  The `SelectMany` will ensure you get all posts back, rather than just one per group.

Through testing, you may find that the second order-by might not be needed.  It just depends on if the order is maintained during grouping or not.  (I haven't checked).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to return the newest post in each group. So I testet your first query, and I got this error `The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.` Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Sorry - I guess you're using Entity Framework then?  Yes, go ahead and use `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: Yes. I use EF. Okay, think I got it correct now, added `FirstOrDefault` and also a final `OrderByDescending`. Final code `GroupBy(x => x.ThreadID).Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Time).FirstOrDefault()).OrderByDescending(x => x.Time)`

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help me :)

Comment: I guess that will work, as you only have one item from each group then.